# Celery - Get task id for current task

Tags: python, django, celery

How can I get the task_id value for a task from within the task? Here's my code:

```
from celery.decorators import task
from django.core.cache import cache

@task
def do_job(path):
    "Performs an operation on a file"

    # ... Code to perform the operation ...

    cache.set(current_task_id, operation_results)
```

The idea is that when I create a new instance of the task, I retrieve the `task_id` from the  task object. I then use the task id to determine whether the task has completed. I **don't** want to keep track of the task by the `path` value because the file is "cleaned up" after the task completes, and may or may not exist.

In the above example, how would I get the value of `current_task_id`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Celery does set some default keyword arguments if the task accepts them.
(you can accept them by either using **kwargs, or list them specifically)

```
@task
def do_job(path, task_id=None):
    cache.set(task_id, operation_results)
```

The list of default keyword arguments is documented here:
http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#default-keyword-arguments

Comment: This is deprecated as of Celery 2.2.0 (see answer below).

Answer (score 141):

### UPDATE: use Balthazar's answer for Celery 3.1+

```
@task(bind=True)
def do_job(self, path):
   cache.set(self.request.id, operation_results)
```

Feel free to upvote his answer.

### Old answer:

Since Celery 2.2.0, information related to the currently executed task is saved to `task.request` (it's called «the context»). So you should get task id from this context (not from keyword arguments, which are deprecated):

```
@task
def do_job(path):
    cache.set(do_job.request.id, operation_results)
```

The list of all available fields is documented here:
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=requestcontext#context

Comment: can you get this id outside of task? for example run task, get id and check with this id if task is finished.

Comment: Yes, you can get id from AsyncResult, and then re-create AsyncResult by id, check the docs http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html

Comment: Use Balthazar's answer if you have Celery 3+. It's more clear & straightforward.

Answer (score 93):

As of celery 3.1, you can use the [`bind`](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context) decorator argument, and have access to the current request:

```
@task(bind=True)
def do_job(self, path):
    cache.set(self.request.id, operation_results)
```

Comment: Is it also possible to know whether it was a Periodic Task or not?