# Get current celery task id anywhere in the thread

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I'd like to get the task id inside a running task,
without knowing which task I'm in.
(That's why I can't use https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096086/245024)

I'd like it to be something like this:

```
@task
def my_task():
    foo()

def foo():
    logger.log(current_task_id)
```

This pattern returns in many different tasks, and I don't want to carry the task context to every inner method call.

One option could be to use the thread local storage, but then I will need to initialize it before the task starts, and clean it after it finished.

Is there something simpler?

Comment: Can you not use 'from celery import current_task; current_task.request.id` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from celery import current_task
print current_task.request.id
```

I'm just copying this from the comment, because it should be an answer, so thanks to @asksol.