# Celery. Get id of current chain

Tags: python, celery

Based on [get id for current task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302320/celery-get-task-id-for-current-task).

I call chain like:

```
chain = (nice_task.s(a=1) |
         task2.s(a=2)).apply_async()
```

Task defined as:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def nice_task(self, a):
    print a
    print self.request.id  # None
    return a
```

How to get id of task inside chain?

I tried to turn on / off `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` - with no effect.

**UPD** Also `self.request` has empty `context`.

Answer (score 7):

Calling the chain will call the tasks inside it and return the **result of the last task** in the chain.

When you are calling chain like this

```
chain = (nice_task.s(a=1) | task2.s(a=2)).apply_async()
```

it is returning result of `task2`. You can verify this by checking `chain.info`

```
In [25]: chain.info
Out[25]: 'task2'

In [26]: chain.id
Out[26]: 'bec26eff-2dfe-4203-aed2-a122d908c905'
```

To access previous task, you need to use `.parent` attribute. `chain.parent` gives you previous task and you can get id from `.id`.

```
In [27]: chain.parent
Out[27]: <AsyncResult: 242d338b-35fe-4f16-be07-36d0d8f2bb53>

In [28]: chain.parent.info
Out[28]: 'task1'

In [29]: chain.parent.id
Out[29]: '242d338b-35fe-4f16-be07-36d0d8f2bb53'
```

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but in my case, it does not matter if I run the chain with `apply_async` or `delay`, the `chain.parent` is always *None*. I have been looking for possible solution all over the Internet, but can't find any clues. :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in my case worked getting the parent id from the `GroupResult`, since chain, chord and group return a `GroupResult`: `AsyncResult(GroupResult.restore(task_id, app=celery_app).parent.id, app=celery_app)`